# Simple example of noflo embedded in webpage for UI

Tags: noflo

Are there any complete examples of how noflo can be embedded in a webpage, including the hookup between noflo and the webpage UI components.

For example, a simple noflo graph for;

1. Date input for date of birth, using datepicker UI on the webpage.
2. Output of age in years and days, using text label on the webpage.

How could this simple example be created as a noflo graph and then embedded in a webpage.

I'm looking for a complete example that can illustrate the approach, which I can then explore extending.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to use either [noflo.asCallback](https://noflojs.org/documentation/embedding/#ascallback) (for single-run "batch processing" style graphs) or [noflo-wrapper](https://github.com/noflo/noflo-wrapper) (for continuously running graphs).

You can see how to package NoFlo with webpack in your project in
https://github.com/noflo/noflo-browser-app